# Get the number of value in an array that has a value

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have this array

```
array (size=5)
  'amazon' => 
    array (size=3)
      'url' => string '' (length=0)
      'display' => string 'Yes' (length=3)
      'best_offer' => string '' (length=0)
  'ebay' => 
    array (size=3)
      'url' => string '' (length=0)
      'display' => string 'Yes' (length=3)
      'best_offer' => string '' (length=0)
  'moosejaw' => 
    array (size=3)
      'url' => string '' (length=0)
      'display' => string 'Yes' (length=3)
      'best_offer' => string '' (length=0)
  'rei' =>
    array (size=3)
      'url' => string '' (length=0)
      'display' => string 'Yes' (length=3)
      'best_offer' => string '' (length=0)
  'jenson' => 
    array (size=3)
      'url' => string 'https://ebay.com' (length=16)
      'display' => string 'Yes' (length=3)
      'best_offer' => string '' (length=0)
```

I need to check if the "url" has a string so if there is then count only how many there are that has a URL

so for this example, this should only display "1"

Any help is very much appreciated :-)

by the way this is what I have at the moment

```
if( have_rows('marketplace_links') ):
    while( have_rows('marketplace_links') ): the_row();

    $value = get_field('marketplace_links', $post->ID);
    echo count($value);

    endwhile;
endif;
```

This code above displays 5 and not 1

Comment: Is this run-able PHP code? where is the `if` condition to check for non-empty `url` field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [**is_string()**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-string.php) : Find whether the type of a variable is string

You can use simple `foreach` with `is_string` and `empty`

```
$counter = 0;
foreach($a as $v){
 is_string($v['url']) && !empty($v['url']) ? ($counter++) : '';
}
```

Working example : https://3v4l.org/rSttF

Comment: Thank you so much, working now, I just added the echo $counter after the foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_column function to get an array of `url` values and remove empty entries by array_filter function

```
 $counter = count(array_filter(array_column($a,'url')));
```